# WinDbg and Intel Visual Fortran

Tags: fortran, windbg

Has anyone used WinDbg to debug an Intel Visual Fortran routine?  If I have the Fortran source file that crashes with an AccViol, how can I use WinDbg to determine the line that is crashing?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same as with a C program. Compile with debugging info, then use `kb` in WinDbg to get a back trace when a fault occurs.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark the response as an "answer" :).